# How to install a super-old unsigned apt-get package?

Tags: apt, 17.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu Zesty 17.04 I'd like to install a cool wallpaper but that apt-get installation fails with following

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/realtime.sunlight.wallpaper/rsw/ubuntu quantal Release: The following signatures were invalid: 471A70A2000BD747ED3E0F6C15A8576D6E46FCAD
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/realtime.sunlight.wallpaper/rsw/ubuntu quantal Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I sign this manually and have `apt-get` always ignore that warning?

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: One option would be to bypass the apt authentication and just download the .deb file directly from http://ppa.launchpad.net/realtime.sunlight.wallpaper/rsw/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk-sunlight/ and then install it with `dpkg -i` or `gdebi`.

Comment: 'Super-old', 'unsigned', and 'ppa' are all warning flags. The software (wallpaper or whatever) is unsupported and has not been tested by any of us for safety, function, or security. Fair warning: You're swimming far from shore in deep water.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one or two package files (which may be the case if you're trying to install wallpapers) then I suggest just downloading the deb files from the respective PPA and install them using

```
sudo dpkg -i <deb-file-name.deb>
```

command.